# wxpython tooltip at specific coordinates

Tags: wxpython, tooltip, coordinates, paint

I have seen lots of similar questions and those answers are what has gotten me this far.

I have an application where all all object are created via DC, so they are all all drawn. (I have had much experience with sizers and 99% of the time sizers ROCK but in this case DC is the best answer.)  So I want to have a tooltip for each element that is drawn and in the case the screen is refreshed and the element is drawn in a different location the tooltip should also move.  My first attempt was with setting a wx.Rect for each drawn item, but I ran into a "hang" situation.  If i was on the the right track track I will attach a code sample but if I should be barking up another tree please let me know before I pull anymore of this hair out my head!!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should try `BalloonTip`

http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/lib.agw.balloontip.html

It creates a new `Frame` for the tooltip and sets it according to coordinates of the object.

Comment: Does BallonTip have the ability to be set to coordinates?  From the example I see that it can be set to an object, but as I am drawing everything, I need to be able to set the tip to coordinates.

Comment: It directly does not provide this facility. But you can achieve this by overriding `SetBalloonShape` method of `BalloonFrame`. There it uses mouse position, but you can specify different calculation for position there.

Comment: I was able to solve my issue using the default tooltip.  I had to make sure that the rect cords were identical to the cords of each drawn element.  The BallonTip was something I had not heard of before and is a good second option for, so I am accepting that as a good answer to my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't like this way but at least it works:

```
def on_tree_task_tooptip(self, event):
    """Handles tree task tooltips"""
    self.m_tree.SetToolTip(None)
    wx.YieldIfNeeded()
    self.m_tree.SetToolTip("my new tooltip")
```